Commutation of matrices
Given a matrix $M\in \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$ that fulfills $[M,X]=0 \, \, \forall X\in \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$, one can show that there exist $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $M=\lambda \mathbb{1}$.
A similar statement can be made if $[M,\mathbb{1} \otimes X]=0 \, \, \forall X\in \text{Mat}_m(\mathbb{C}) \, \, \, (m<n)$. Then there exist a $Y\in\text{Mat}_{n-m}(\mathbb{C})$ s.t. $M = Y \otimes \mathbb{1}$.
I'm wondering if a similar statement can be made in the following case.
Given $$ [M, \bigoplus_k \mathbb{1}_k \otimes X_k] = 0 \quad \forall X_k \in \text{Mat}(\mathbb{C})$$ is it also true that there exist $Y_k \in \text{Mat}(\mathbb{C})$ s.t.
$$ M = \bigoplus_k Y_k \otimes \mathbb{1} $$
